# 'Cropping' a list in c#

Tags: c#, collections

Given a Generic `IList` of some type, which contains a number of items, is there any way of 'cropping' this list, so that only the fist x items are preserved, and the rest discarded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existing answers create a new list containing a subset of items from the original list.

If you need to truncate the original list in-place then these are your options:

```
// if your list is a concrete List<T>
if (yourList.Count > newSize)
{
    yourList.RemoveRange(newSize, yourList.Count - newSize);
}

// or, if your list is an IList<T> or IList but *not* a concrete List<T>
while (yourList.Count > newSize)
{
    yourList.RemoveAt(yourList.Count - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks all, but accepting this one for the first option, as it's a nice succinct in-place technique.

Comment: One thing to note is that if the number of items to keep is just a fraction of the original list, then just taking the ones you need should be faster and consume less memory. I'm not sure, but I don't *think* that `List<T>` will shrink itself upon removal, leaving you with a list that is much larger than you need. If you create a new list, the entire old list is eligible for collection. (Although in practice, this may not matter much)

Comment: @Isak: Indeed, and these days I'd probably use something similar to your answer in most situations; but sometimes you have no option but to manipulate the existing object in-place.

Answer (score 14):

If you can use Linq, it's just a matter of doing

```
// Extraact the first 5 items in myList to newList
var newList = myList.Take(5).ToList();

// You can combine with .Skip() to extract items from the middle
var newList = myList.Skip(2).Take(5).ToList();
```

Note that the above will create new lists with the 5 elements. If you just want to iterate over the first 5 elements, you don't have to create a new list:

```
foreach (var oneOfTheFirstFive in myList.Take(5))
     // do stuff
```

Comment: +1 for including the fact that you don't need to do .ToList() unless you explicitly need to create a new list.

Answer (score 1):

you have a very simple way to:

```
IList<T> list = [...]; //initialize
IList<T> newList = new List<T>(max);
for (i=0; i<max; i++) newList.Add(list[i]);
```

Note: max MUST be less or equal then list length (otherwise you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it just with the `IList<T>` interface, then something like this is the solution:

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= numberOfElementsToKeep; --i) {
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Working backwards from the end of the list here, in order to avoid moving around data which will be deleted in subsequent loop iterations.